# Converter String para Timestamp Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conversão-de-tipo

No df estou recebendo uma coluna com o tipo String e preciso converter ela para Timestamp para integração em outro banco.

Tentei dessa forma:

```
 if str(df.head(1)).__contains__('timeline.entrada.date'):
    df_final['dataDeEntrada'] = df['timeline.entrada.date'].astype('timestamp')
 else:
    df_final['dataDeEntrada'] = ''
```

Recebendo retorno assim:

```
TypeError: data type 'timestamp' not understood
```

e também assim:

```
 if str(df.head(1)).__contains__('timeline.entrada.date'):
    df_final['dataDeEntrada'] = df['timeline.entrada.date'].to_timestamp()
 else:
    df_final['dataDeEntrada'] = ''
```

Recebendo retorno assim:

```
TypeError: unsupported Type RangeIndex
```

Qual é a forma correta de eu conseguir realizar essa conversão ?

Comment: O método para isso seria o `to_datetime`. Veja [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score -2):

Caso você esteja criando o df a partir de alguma base de dados, um csv por exemplo, existe um parâmetro que chamado `parse_dates` do qual você pode passar uma lista com as colunas que você quer que sejam convetidas para timestamped.

Agora, caso você receba o df já criado, você pode user o método `to_timestamp`

### Referência

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_#pandas.read_csv
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_#pandas.read_excel
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=read_#pandas.read_sql
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html?highlight=to_time#pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp

NT. O método read_json não tem esse parâmetro.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).